# Fill the whole content area with Navigation Framework

Tags: silverlight

in my Silverlight 4 application, I use the navigation framework to display different pages. In a test page, I split a grid in two halfes with a simple textbox and a rectangle each:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF9696DA"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FFDAC296" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <sdk:GridSplitter x:Name="GridSplitterTreeViewArea" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="5"/>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TreeView Area" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Main Area" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

I want this page to fill the whole content area of the screen, or in other words ... the remaining space of the browser window. But it just not stretches, it is just as big as the textboxes need to display. I have checked the content control, but it is (standard) set to stretch

```
    <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" Style="{StaticResource ContentBorderStyle}">
        <navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Style="{StaticResource ContentFrameStyle}" Source="/EditorDisplayArea" Navigated="ContentFrame_Navigated" NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed" Padding="1" Template="{StaticResource ContentFrameTemplate}">
            <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
                <uriMapper:UriMapper>
                    <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/Views/EditorDisplayArea.xaml" />
                    <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml" />
                </uriMapper:UriMapper>
            </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
        </navigation:Frame>
    </Border>
```

How is it possible to let the page fill the remaining space?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have found it!

The problem was within the ContentFrameTemplate. I use this to change the ContentPresenter to TransitioningContentControl, by creating a copy of the default control template and exchanging the control types . It seems that the Vertical/HorizontalCONTENTAlignement of the ContentPresenter is Stretch by standard, but not for the TransitioningContentControl. So the solution was to add those to the template.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ContentFrameTemplate" TargetType="navigation:Frame">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
        <toolkit:TransitioningContentControl 
            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
            Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>

    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I found it on [Shawn Wildermuths Blog](http://wildermuth.com/2010/07/16/Bring_Back_Page_Transitions_to_the_Windows_Phone_List_Application_Template) in his comments.

Frank